# what are the consequences if I set the id parameter(in DA layer) to final?

Tags: java, spring, software-design, data-access-layer

if the id that I get from database won't change during process(which usually don't), why can't I set it final?
and by "can't" I mean I didn't see any software that did it before.

I searched in google but I didn't find anything relevant. if this question asked before please excuse me and tell me to delete this topic.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why don't you go ahead and do it and check what the consequences are. Every design is different, I suppose you may not find a precedence which is close to your case.